# Simple multi-div page crashes Chrome.

Tags: google-chrome, html, crash, resize

I hope it's just my installation, although I have disabled all extensions.
All i have to do is resize the window horizontally and vertically a few times, and it will crash.  I could not get IE to crash. 
I can't believe something so simple would blow it up.
Chrome verison 30.0.1599.101

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script  type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<style type="text/css">

#mainDiv {
background-color: grey;
position: absolute;
top: 70px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
}

#innerDiv1 {
background-color: blue;
position: relative;
width:31%;
float: left;
padding:1px;
margin:10px;
}

#innerDiv2 {
background-color: yellow;
position: relative;
width:31%;
float: left;
padding:1px;
margin:10px;
}

#innerDiv3 {
background-color: red;
position: relative;
width:31%;
float: left;
padding:1px;
margin:10px;
}

#content {
width: 100% ;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
background-color:green;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="mainDiv"  >
Stuff here
    <div id="content"> 
        <div id="innerDiv1">
            Inner 1
        </div>

        <div id="innerDiv2">
            Inner 2
        </div>

        <div id="innerDiv3">
            Inner 3
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have "Version 26.0.1410.64 m" , no extensions and it doesn't crash for me. It could be one of your extensions, if not then your version